# Nest.js can't inject providers into guard

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

> [Nest] 20308  - 16.12.2021, 17:08:50   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest
> can't resolve dependencies of the AuthGuard (?, AuthService,
> Reflector). Please make sure that the argument UserService at index
> [0] is available in the AppModule context.
>
> Potential solutions:
>
> - If UserService is a provider, is it part of the current AppModule?
> - If UserService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AppModule?   @Module({
>   imports: [ /* the Module containing UserService */ ]   })

**Auth Module**

```ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { JsonWebToken } from 'src/auth/jsonwebtoken';
import { UserModule } from 'src/user/user.module';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Code, CodeSchema } from './db/code.schema';

@Module({
  imports: [
    UserModule,
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{name: Code.name, schema: CodeSchema}]),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, JsonWebToken],
  exports: [AuthService]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

**User Module**

```ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { UserController } from './user.controller';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { User, UserSchema } from './db/user.schema';
import { UserSettingsService } from './settings.service';
import { UserSettings, UserSettingsSchema } from './db/settings.schema';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{name: User.name, schema: UserSchema}]),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{name: UserSettings.name, schema: UserSettingsSchema}]),
  ],
  providers: [UserService, UserSettingsService],
  controllers: [UserController],
  exports: [UserService, UserSettingsService]
})
export class UserModule {}
```

**App Module**

```ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { ServicesModule } from './services/services.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost:27017/user-service'),
    UserModule,
    AuthModule,
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    ServicesModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Guard**

```ts
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { UserService } from 'src/user/user.service';
import { Request } from 'express';
import { AuthService } from 'src/auth/auth.service';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    @Inject('UserService') private userService: UserService, 
    @Inject('AuthService') private authService: AuthService, 
    private reflector: Reflector
  ) {}

  canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    //some code....
    //passed
    return true;
  }
}
```

I just want to inject the *AuthService* and *UserService* into the *AuthGuard* but I always get the same error. I also searched for the problem but got nothing that fixed the problem.

I'd be glad for your help and very thankful!

Comment: I believe you can drop those `@Inject('UserService')` and `@Inject('AuthService')`, you don't need them as you're using the concrete class as a type. Also, which version of Nestjs are you using?

Comment: btw `AuthGuard` is used in which nestjs module? Because the target module should have imported `UserModule`, I guess

Comment: Oh yeah. I fixed the problem by creating a module forward reference. The two modules `AuthModule` and `UserModule` are needed in the `AuthGuard`. So like imported the modules into another.

Comment: But thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**AuthModule**

```
import { forwardRef, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { JsonWebToken } from 'src/auth/jsonwebtoken';
import { UserModule } from 'src/user/user.module';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Code, CodeSchema } from './db/code.schema';

@Module({
  imports: [
    forwardRef(() => UserModule), //added this
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{name: Code.name, schema: CodeSchema}]),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, JsonWebToken],
  exports: [AuthService]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

**UserModule**

```
import { forwardRef, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { UserController } from './user.controller';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { User, UserSchema } from './db/user.schema';
import { UserSettingsService } from './settings.service';
import { UserSettings, UserSettingsSchema } from './db/settings.schema';
import { AuthModule } from 'src/auth/auth.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{name: User.name, schema: UserSchema}]),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{name: UserSettings.name, schema: UserSettingsSchema}]),
    forwardRef(() => AuthModule) //added this
  ],
  providers: [UserService, UserSettingsService],
  controllers: [UserController],
  exports: [UserService, UserSettingsService]
})
export class UserModule {}
```

Both modules are needed in the `AuthGuard` so I created a module forward reference because they're depending on each other.